# Concatenate the Kendo Grid Columns

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What I am trying to do is to concatenate or merge two columns in single column in kendo Grid.

I tried to do it but no success so far also searched for it but still not getting how to do it??

I want to concatenate two or three columns in single e-g

```
First Name

Middle Name

Last Name
```

All should be shown in single

```
Full Name
```

Here is some of my kendogrid code.

```
$("#EmployeeGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:{
            transport: {
                read: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/list_view"
            },
            schema:{
                data: "data"
            }
        },

        columns: [
            {
                field: "EmployeeID",
                hidden:true
            },
            {
                field:"LastName"
            },
            { field: "LastName"+"FirstName",
                title:"Full Name"
            },
            {
                field:"City",
                title:"City"
            },
            {
                field:"AddressLine1",
                title:"Address 1"
            },

            {
                field:"WorkPhone",
                title:"WorkPhone"
            },
            {
                field:"MobileNo",
                title:"Mobile No"
            },
            {command: { text: "View", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"},
            {command: { text: "Edit", click: EditUserDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to use [template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template) column:

```
template:"#= FirstName # #= MidName # #= LastName #"
```

Comment: so how to use it in my case??
Should i just go directly put it there?

Comment: yes , no field needs to be specified, just template like shown in the documentation link above

Answer (score 0):

Another example that worked in Angular 8:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="LastName" title="Last, First">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
       {{ dataItem.LastName}}, {{ dataItem.FirstName }}
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="MiddleName" title="Middle"></kendo-grid-column>
```